Error: creating joined report (file and content + custom object)
I'm creating a joined report between a custom report and file/content report to brings information from the related Note on that custom object. When I click "add block" to add the 2nd report, I get the following error: "Choose a different report type. This one has no common fields with the other report types in this joined report." What could it be?


Please edit your question and show your data model and report fields, similar to this question.
